# Getting a string using inline ASM

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, hook, inline-assembly

What I am doing is injecting a DLL into a running process. I then proceed to check some informations about that process, such as versions etc. My problem is I cannot seem to access a string in the assembly file, that contains the revision number I want to doublecheck. Here is what I have so far:

```
__declspec(naked) void CheckBuild()
{
    char* revision;
    __asm {
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        pushad
        pushfd

        mov revision, dword ptr 0x5F5200
    }

    printf("Detected revision ID: %u\n", revision);

    __asm {
        popfd
        popad
        add esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        retn
    }
}
```

For this training stuff, the address of the string, that I get through IDA and that I checked using CheatEngine and OllyDbg, is constant.

However, no matter what I try, I always get 0x5F5200 back in decimal, which is definitely not what I expect. I almost tried everything, including lea and others, but I still don't get the valid string.

Can anyone point me to the correct direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are missing the "dereferencing":

   `mov revision, dword ptr [0x5F5200]`

which isn't a valid instruction since it has two indirects, so

```
mov eax, dword ptr [0x5F5200]
mov revision, eax
```

1. if the value is indeed a string, there's something else wrong:

   - if the string is stored at 0x5F5200, you would simply use

   `printf("Detected revision ID: %s\n", 0x5F5200)`

   - if the address of the string is stored at 0x5F5200, you would use

   `printf("Detected revision ID: %s\n", revision)`
2. String format

If the string is unicode, you would use

```
printf("Detected revision ID: %S\n", revision);
```

(note that with wprintf, it's the other way 'round: %s for a wide character string, and %s for a char string).

Finally, if the string is not guaranteed to be zero-terminated but has a fixed length, you need to copy from the address to a local buffer and ensure zero termination before the print.